# Retrieve string between characters and assign on new variable using awk in bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, awk, terminal

I'm new to bash scripting, I'm learning how commands work, I stumble in this problem,

I have a file `/home/fedora/file.txt`

Inside of the file is like this:

```
[apple] This is a fruit.
[ball] This is a sport's equipment.
[cat] This is an animal.
```

What I wanted is to retrieve words between "[" and "]".

What I tried so far is :

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
do
    echo $line | awk -F"[" '{print$2}' | awk -F"]" '{print$1}'
done < /home/fedora/file.txt
```

I can print the words between "[" and "]".

Then I wanted to put the echoed word into a variable but i don't know how to.

Any help I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
variable="$(echo $line | awk -F"[" '{print$2}' | awk -F"]" '{print$1}')"
```

or

```
variable="$(awk -F'[\[\]]' '{print $2}' <<< "$line")"
```

or complete

```
while IFS='[]' read -r foo fruit rest; do echo $fruit; done < file
```

or with an array:

```
while IFS='[]' read -ra var; do echo "${var[1]}"; done < file
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I also just learn that this also works: `word=$line
        word=${word##*[}
        word=${word%%]*}`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `awk`, you can use the native *parameter expansion/substring extraction* provided by bash. Below `#` indicates a trim from the left, while `%` is used to trim from the right. (**note:** a single `#` or `%` indicates removal up to the *first* occurrence, while `##` or `%%` indicates removal of *all* occurrences):

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -r "$1" ] || {    ## validate input is readable
    printf "error: insufficient input. usage: %s filename\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

## read each line and separate label and value
while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    label=${line#[}     # trim initial [ from left
    label=${label%%]*}  # trim through ] from right
    value=${line##*] }  # trim from left through '[ '
    printf " %-8s -> '%s'\n" "$label" "$value"
done <"$1"

exit 0
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/labels.txt
[apple] This is a fruit.
[ball] This is a sport's equipment.
[cat] This is an animal.
```

**Output**

```
$ bash readlabel.sh dat/labels.txt
 apple    -> 'This is a fruit.'
 ball     -> 'This is a sport's equipment.'
 cat      -> 'This is an animal.'
```